# Switching between multiple JDK's

Tags: java

Switching between JDK's

```
export JDK8_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_361.jdk

export JAVA_8_HOME=$JDK8_HOME/Contents/Home

alias usejdk8='export JAVA_HOME=$JDK8_HOME'

export JDK11_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk

export JAVA_11_HOME=$JDK11_HOME/Contents/Home

alias usejdk11='export JAVA_HOME=$JDK11_HOME'

export JDK17_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk

export JAVA_17_HOME=$JDK17_HOME/Contents/Home

alias usejdk17='export JAVA_HOME=$JDK17_HOME'

export JDK20_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk

export JAVA_20_HOME=$JDK20_HOME/Contents/Home

alias usejdk20='export JAVA_HOME=$JDK20_HOME'

export GRAALVM17_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1

export GRAALVM_HOME=$GRAALVM17_HOME

alias usegraalvm17='export GRAALVM_HOME=$GRAALVM17_HOME'

export GRAALVM20_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-20.jdk

export GRAALVM_HOME=$GRAALVM20_HOME

alias usegraalvm20='export GRAALVM_HOME=$GRAALVM20_HOME'

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAALVM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This is my .zshrc file. When I write command `usejdkX` my JDK is still on JDK 20.

I've multiple JDK's on my MacOS Ventura and I've Define environment variables for all of them in .zshrc file but I can't switch between them. Can anybody help me to fix my problem please.

Comment: It might simpler to use SDKMAN! In any case, you don't provide any clue or error as to what the problem is. Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: The last row only gets executed once, when you start zsh. You will have to update the PATH variable after changing the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Or to put it another way ... the variables in `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAALVM_HOME/bin:$PAT` are expanded **before** a value bound to `PATH`.  (Posix shells don't support "deferred expansion".)

Answer (score 2):

I agree you should use something like [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), but I see you have [GraalVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM) to consider too. I don't do zsh but I'd be inclined to do something like this in bash as adding/removing DKs is trivial. Of course you could do this just for Graal but it's good to do both at once. Of course the below would have to be sourced, either directly or via an alias.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Usage: $(basename ${0}) <Version number>"  
    exit 1
fi

jdks=( \
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_361.jdk
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk
)

graals=( \
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-20.jdk
)

version=$1
JAVA_HOME=''
GRAALVM_HOME=''
len_jdks=${#jdks[@]}

for((i = 0;i < len_jdks;i++)); do
  jdk=${jdks[$i]}
  if [[ $jdk =~ .*$version.* ]]; then
      JAVA_HOME=$jdk
      break
  fi
done
len_graals=${#graals[@]}
for((i = 0;i < len_graals;i++)); do
  graal=${graals[$i]}
  if [[ $graal =~ .*$version.* ]]; then
      GRAALVM_HOME=$graal
      break
  fi
done
echo "JAVA_HOME is $JAVA_HOME"
echo "GRAALVM_HOME is $GRAALVM_HOME"
export "$JAVA_HOME"
export "$GRAALVM_HOME"
```